# Crash in com.paymob.acceptsdk.PayActivity void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar after migrating Project to AndroidX

Tags: android, android-actionbar, androidx

After migrating the project to AndroidX im getting this crash

```
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{oackagename/com.paymob.acceptsdk.PayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

,      `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference`

PayActivity is activity in payment gate SDK and i cannot change its code.

How i can the activity :

```
Intent pay_intent = new Intent(this, PayActivity.class);

putNormalExtras(pay_intent);
pay_intent.putExtra(PayActivityIntentKeys.SAVE_CARD_DEFAULT, true);
pay_intent.putExtra(PayActivityIntentKeys.SHOW_ALERTS, showSaveCard);
pay_intent.putExtra(PayActivityIntentKeys.SHOW_SAVE_CARD, showSaveCard);
pay_intent.putExtra(PayActivityIntentKeys.THEME_COLOR, 0x8033B5E5);

startActivityForResult(pay_intent, ACCEPT_PAYMENT_REQUEST);
```

UPDATE : 
library link :

```
implementation 'com.paymob:acceptsdk:1.0.6'
implementation 'net.authorize:accept-sdk-android:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Does your integrated SDK has support for AndroidX? If yes then possibly use that updated SDK otherwise one other solution is to change your `AppTheme` to `MaterialComponents with Bridge` version support. Hope it helps. *(make sure you've enabled jetifier in your project)*

Comment: can you explain the materialcomponent with bridge part please? and enableJetifier is true

Comment: What is your `AppTheme` from *styles.xml*? (Please share you code).

Comment: @style/AppTheme.NoActionBar

Comment: <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: I was suggesting to add something like this `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">`, here add parent theme to your theme from `MaterialComponents` but use `Bridge` for backward compatibility. *(There are plenty of other themes with Bridge config in MaterialComponents, use your suitable one)*

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your `Manifest` file

```
 <activity android:name="com.paymob.acceptsdk.PayActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"/>
```

Comment: not working. Crash is still coming

Comment: sadly since this way years ago and i am no longer working on the project the ware using paymob i am not sure what is the case now.

but please add your solution when you figure it out

Comment: Yes I got the solution.

Comment: maybe you can add it in a comment, it might help someone in the future